# How does FLASK-RQ2 calls a function using the job decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, redis, queue

Hello I am new to Redis and Redis Queue
I am trying to use the Flask-RQ2 library to execute a function but my function is not executing when I add my function to the queue
Looking at [Flask-RQ2](https://github.com/rq/Flask-RQ2/blob/58eedf6f0cd7bcde4ccd787074762ea08f531337/src/flask_rq2/app.py#L278) it includes a callable so why is my function not being executed

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_rq2 import RQ

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['RQ_REDIS_URL'] = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'

rq = RQ(app)


@rq.job
def foo(a,b):
    print(a+b)
    return a + b;


@app.route('/')
def index():
    job = foo.queue(5,9)
    print(foo.queue(8,8))
    return 'Job queued!'



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

This the output from Redis

```
1570238667.183464 [0 127.0.0.1:64377] "MULTI"
1570238667.183506 [0 127.0.0.1:64377] "SADD" "rq:queues" "rq:queue:default"
1570238667.183522 [0 127.0.0.1:64377] "HSET" "rq:job:db248b95-64bd-4300-b562-4781a7136e3c" "status" "queued"
1570238667.183547 [0 127.0.0.1:64377] "HMSET" "rq:job:db248b95-64bd-4300-b562-4781a7136e3c" "created_at" "2019-10-05T01:24:27.181463Z" "data" "x\x9ck`\x99*\xc3\x00\x01\x1a=<\xf1\xf1\xb9\x89\x99y\xf1\xf1zi\xf9\xf9S\xfc\xbcY\xbd9\xdb\xa6\xd4N)\x99\xa2\a\x00\xbbl\x0bp" "origin" "default" "description" "__main__.foo(5, 9)" "enqueued_at" "2019-10-05T01:24:27.182076Z" "timeout" "180" "result_ttl" "500" "status" "queued"
1570238667.183641 [0 127.0.0.1:64377] "RPUSH" "rq:queue:default" "db248b95-64bd-4300-b562-4781a7136e3c"
1570238667.183672 [0 127.0.0.1:64377] "EXEC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually start a worker to run the jobs.

https://flask-rq2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-worker

```
# Creates a worker that handle jobs in ``default`` queue.
default_worker = rq.get_worker()
default_worker.work(burst=True)

# Creates a worker that handle jobs in both ``simple`` and ``low`` queues.
low_n_simple_worker = rq.get_worker('low', 'simple')
low_n_simple_worker.work(burst=True)
```

The first example should work for your case.
If you have a manage.py you can write it into a manager command and run it from there.

Comment: as soon as I add this to my codebase, I get this error when developing locally:

`ValueError: signal only works in main thread` 
From what I gathered, it is only an issue when using Flask in debug mode / locally, and will not be a problem in production or staging environments... But how do I deal with this error?